# How to mutate ServerWebExchange from Spring Webflux Filter

Tags: spring-webflux

I am trying to decrypt the payload from request ServerWebExchange and log the original payload and decrypted one,

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        String originalRequestJson = getRequestBodyAsJsonString(serverWebExchange);
        String decryptedRequestJson = getDecryptedRequestBody(originalRequestJson);
        log.info("Request :: Original {} Decrypted {}", originalRequestJson, decryptedRequestJson);
        ServerWebExchange mutatedServerWebExchange = mutateServerWebExchange(serverWebExchange, decryptedRequestJson);
        return webFilterChain.filter(mutatedServerWebExchange);
    }
    
    private ServerWebExchange **mutateServerWebExchange**(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
            String decryptedRequestJson) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private String **getDecryptedRequestBody**(String originalRequestJson) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private String **getRequestBodyAsJsonString**(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

How to implement the method **mutateServerWebExchange**, **getRequestBodyAsJsonString**, **getDecryptedRequestBody**

I tried my own, but i am facing **Content is no longer available for the downstream**